# objC - empty array of types

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In  C, C++, C# you can have arrays of a certain type like int[].
In objC a NSArray can have a different type for every element.
If you want to have an NSArray of type x, you now can just treat the type of the element at index 0 as type of the array, meaning if [anArray objectAtIndex:0] is a NSString, you treat all objects as a NSString and throw an error, if any element is of a different type than the element at index 0. It is ugly, but  you can simulate typed arrays that way.
Now, in C# it is even possible to have an empty array of type x with 0 elements.
However an empty NSArray of course has no element, not even at index 0, so there is no typeinfo in there.

Now if an objC app gets an array from a C# app or vice versa and the C# app in some situations sends or expects an empty array, the receiving side has to know the type of, how can get/set this typeinfo in objC?

Of course I could use C-arrays instead of NSArrays, but if you want to store a c-array in a NSDictionary, you have to put it into a NSValue first and a NSValue does not offer a possibility to store the size of a dynamically allocated  c-array.

Is there any better option than to implement a new class "CArrayValue" for storing C_Arrays with typeinfo and size in a NSDictionary?

Comment: Using the type of the first element isn't a great plan; if you're storing NSStrings, for example, the first one might be (private) subclass of NSString like NSCFString, and others might be other subclasses of NSString. How are you supposed to know what superclass to enforce? You need to store this information elsewhere.

Comment: You can use [NSObject isMemberOfClass] on an object to check, if it is an instancce of a certain subclass of NSString, but you can also use [NSObject isKindOfClass] to find out, if it is an instance of any subclass of NSString.

Comment: Graham Lee wrote a nice blog post on that topic: [On type safety and making it harder to write buggy code](http://blog.securemacprogramming.com/2010/05/on-type-safety-and-making-it-harder-to-write-buggy-code/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a wrapper for NSArray, one that contains a type key as instance variable and an NSArray. In that way you should be able to easily control the type of the array. Also what you could do to prevent adding types that are not allowed, is writing some methods that would remove / add items t o the array / initialize it.

Comment: Seems to be a suitable approach, but why a wrapper and not a subclass?

Comment: @Kaiserludi NSArray is actually a cluster of classes, and any subclass of NSArray basically has to implement the fundamental array operations (`count`, `objectAtIndex:`) itself, which means providing your own storage mechanism and memory management. By wrapping NSArray, you can skip that part and just enforce your constraints.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW76

Comment: argh, I should not click enter before entering the text for link:
Just had a look here at the part subclassing class clusters, and I think a Composite object, which subclasses the class cluster by wrapping it and then overwriting the primitive methods to call the ones of the embedded object would be suitable, as you do not have to wrap all the API, but can inherit the methods, you do not need to overwrite, and this way have the advantages of subclassing, but still have the wrapper-advantage of not having to implement your own storage

Comment: See also: [When to Make a Subclass][1]. I would second (or third) the idea of composition rather than subclassing. See `NSAttributedString`, is implemented using composition rather than by subclassing `NSString`. [1]: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/AddingBehaviortoaCocoaProgram/AddingBehaviorCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH5-SW22

Comment: I now have composited an EGArray as subclass of NSArray, holding a NSArray as member and overwriting all methods, which are initialising the NSArray or are returning a new NSArray with additional elements.
Now I am writing EGMutableArray, but I have the problem, that I can't inherit from EGArray AND NSMutableArray, so I can't pass the EGMutableArray to methods, expecting a NSMutableArray, AND methods, expecting an EGArray. Any ideas, how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Kaiserludi just do it the same way, just wrap an NSMutableArray instead of an NSArray :P

Comment: yes, of course, but I would like to pass the EGMutableArray as an EGArray and as a NSMutableArray. Would be no big deal in C++ with its multiple inheritcance, but thats not allowed in objC.

Comment: Hmm, seems to be the best to not let an EGMutableArray be passed to methods, expecting a NSMutableArray, these methods could rely on the ability of a NSMutableArray to store objects of different types and the same type, so EGMutableArray would violate the Liskov substitution principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov%5Fsubstitution%5Fprinciple) if it would inherit the interface from NSMutableArray.